# How "simple" can a counterexample to the Continuum Hypothesis be?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

For this question, work in your choice of ZFC or ZF+[DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice). ​ ​ ​ ​ ( CH ​ = ​ the [Continuum Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) )

[Analytic sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) are [known to have](https://mathoverflow.net/a/72257/5810) the [perfect set property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property), so they cannot be counterexamples to CH. ​ Is there any consistency result regarding co-analytic counterexamples to CH?

If yes, what about with bounds on the complexity of the

[continuous function from the Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set#Definition) onto the set's complement?

For example:

Can the function's graph be [hyperarithmetical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory#Hyperarithmetical_sets)?

Can the function be computable in the sense of receiving the input as an [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is consistent that there is a coanalytic set (i.e., $\Pi^1_1$) which has size $\aleph_1$, while the continuum is arbitrarily large.

You can find this explained in:

> *Greg Hjorth, Leigh Humphries, and Arnold W. Miller*, MR 3087073 [**Universal sets for pointsets properly on the $n$th level of the projective hierarchy**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2178/jsl.7801160), *J. Symbolic Logic* **78** (2013), no. 1, 237--244.

Comment: Are you referring to the ​ "We use it in a way similar to Martin-Solovay [12] who showed that assuming ..." ​ sentence? ​ ​ ​ If no, then where in that paper is your answer's starting sentence explained? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: It is shortly after that, just after the proof of Lemma 3.8 (keywords: self-constructible reals).

Comment: Do you know of any reference for their "equiconsistent" statement? ​ (top of page 238) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky: Just do the usual forcing to get Martin's Axiom over $L$. That forcing is ccc, so it preserves cardinals.